# Return specified output argument number from function

Tags: python, function

I have the following function:

```
def my_fun():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    return a,b,c
```

How do I now only get the second output argument from the function? I can for example do:

```
a,b,c = my_fun()
print(b)
```

But I  don't want to specify a and c. Only b in this case. So I want to do something like:

```
print(my_fun([1])) # which should give me 2.
```

To get the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rearrange it slightly:

```
print(my_fun()[1])
```

Your function is returning a tuple, and [you can subset tuples with integer indices](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#common-sequence-operations) like you would lists, because tuples are sequence types.

Answer (score 1):

You'd index your return value

```
>>> my_fun()[1]
2
```

Otherwise as written `my_fun([1])` looks like you are passing the list `[1]` as an argument to `my_fun`.

Note that as a convention `_` is used to indicate a value that you do not care about, e.g.

```
_, b, _ = my_func()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your function returns three values, you will always get three values. You can ignore them a few ways, though:

```py
_, b, _ = my_fun()
b = my_fun()[1]
```